# Compare and set a new date based on the compared date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date

```
GradeDate
```

I need to see

```
if GradeDate falls after 6 p.m. on the 20th of the month it is on. 

then set a new variable to be GradeDate2 at month+1 and always on the 15th.
```

Meaning GradeDate of '2022-11-21' will generate a GradeDate2 of '2022-12-15'.

I don't want a straight answer but I would appreciate some hints. I am very familiar with moment and prefer to achieve this via moment.

My dates are already in unix style.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, your challenge with it and we can better assist you here.

Comment: FWIW moment is deprecated and the authors suggest alternatives i.e. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 0):

No need really for any library; this is just a matter of date manipulation.
Here is a VERY verbose example to show in detail what I was doing.  I set up an array with various test dates - not all inclusive but should be enough to get you started.  I used UTC dates but if you need to adjust for a specific time zone I will leave that exercise to you.

```js
let testDates = [new Date(),
  new Date('2022-11-20T23:59:00Z'),
  new Date('2022-11-20T23:59:59.999Z'),
  new Date('2022-11-20T18:00:00Z'),
  new Date('2022-11-21T00:00:00Z'),
  new Date('2023-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
  new Date('2023-01-21T00:00:00Z'),
  new Date('2022-11-19T23:59:59Z')
];
const lastHour = 18;
const lastDay = 20;
const setDay = 15;
testDates.forEach((testDate, index) => {
  console.log('testDate:' + index + '\t', testDate.toISOString())
  let GradeDate = new Date(testDate);
  let dateOfGradeDate = new Date(testDate);
  dateOfGradeDate.setUTCDate(lastDay);
  dateOfGradeDate.setUTCHours(lastHour);
  dateOfGradeDate.setUTCMinutes(0);
  dateOfGradeDate.setUTCSeconds(0);
  dateOfGradeDate.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
  let GradeDate2 = new Date(dateOfGradeDate);
  //if past the 20th of current month move to next month
  let shouldUseNextMonth = testDate > dateOfGradeDate;
  if (shouldUseNextMonth) {
    GradeDate2.setUTCMonth(GradeDate.getMonth() + 1);
    GradeDate2.setUTCDate(setDay);
    GradeDate2.setUTCHours(0);
  }
  console.log('GradeDate:\t', GradeDate.toISOString());
  console.log('GradeDate2:\t', GradeDate2.toISOString());
});
```